# How can I package a Java application for Mac so that it can accept any file dropped on it?

Tags: java, macos, jpackage

I'm creating a file upload utility in Java, and packaging it as a Mac OS X Application. I'm using Java 17 and jpackage to create my application. Everything is working, except I can't figure out how to use --associate-file with a wildcard so that any file, including directories, can be dropped onto my application. I need this so that my application can upload the file(s) or directories to the cloud.

[UPDATE]

I ended up fixing the problem by parsing the generated Info.plist, removing the jpackage-generated array associated with the CFBundleDocumentTypes, and replacing it with my own array. This seems very kludgey, and I would welcome any answers that explain how to do it using jpackage without post-processing.

The fixed version looks like this:

```
  <key>CFBundleDocumentTypes</key>
  <array><dict><key>CFBundleTypeExtensions</key><array><string>*</string></array><key>CFBundleTypeRole</key><string>Editor</string></dict></array>
```

Reference documentation on the CFBundleDocumentTypes can be found at https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CoreFoundationKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009249-101685-TPXREF107

Comment: For drag and drop, you don’t use file associations.  File associations are for the default desktop operation (such as double-clicking) on a file.

Comment: OK, how can I get it so that any file can be dragged to my application?

Comment: I may have misunderstood.  When you say “dropped onto my application,” do you mean dropped into the application’s window, or dropped into the application’s desktop icon?

Comment: Application desktop icon. I am trying to create a Java file uploader utility, which allows you to drag the icon of any file(s) or directory(ies) to its icon in the dock.

Comment: That’s a tricky one.  I thought I had read that wildcard MIME types could be in the file association properties files, but now I can’t find any documentation confirming that.

Answer (score 0):

The 'post processing' seems to be a good way, yet you want to get rid of it.
I guess it is happening post installation, which means you still need to process data after the installer has run.

There is one other possibility: Override JPackage resources.
If you want to know about [resources used](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/jpackage/override-jpackage-resources.html#GUID-405708DC-0243-49FC-84D9-B2A7F0A011A9), the documentation lists them and they include Info.plist for the Apple Mac.

Now you'd have to extract the given Info.plist, place it with whatever additions you want to have in a 'resources' directory and specify that on the JPackage command line.

See also [Overriding JPackage Resources](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/jpackage/override-jpackage-resources.html#GUID-1B718F8B-B68D-4D46-B1DB-003D7729AAB6).